# Does maven-release-plugin also do what maven-compiler-plugin does?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

In project pom.xml is it required to include both maven-release-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin? The reason I want the release plugin is because I want to release the project at the end of a sprint/release. I understand that the compiler plugin will compile the source code, however I am not sure if the release plugin will also compile the source code, apart from updating the pom and checking out/in to scm.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If unspecified, Maven will know what to do when it needs to compile the code. However, in order to be able to control things like source and target versions, you will need to have a declaration of the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

It is generally good practice, to explicitly define the plugins you are using, along with their configurations and above all their versions, so that you have a guarantee of what was working.

Comment: Is there an order in which both these plugins should be mentioned in the pom.xml? Or Maven will automatically determine the order in which the plugin will be executed. Also these plugins need to be mentioned in the root pom.xml or the module's pom.xml? Thanks

Comment: These plugins execute in different `<phases/>`. The `maven-compiler-plugin` has two goals which will be invoked: `compiler:compile` (executing in phase `compile`) and compiler:testCompile (executing in phase `test-compile`). For details on phases check here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html. Define them in the parent pom in a `<pluginManagement/>` section and then use them in the child.

Answer (score 0):

What the Maven Release Plugin does is described [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html).
Your question is about the bullet "Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm everything is in working order". There is not that much magic here. What happens is that the maven-release-plugin will start a new Maven session. It will execute "mvn verify" in the same folder where you ran "mvn release:prepare".
All the steps done by the maven-release-plugin could also be done by hand, but that's asking for mistakes.